# Checking for values left of a cell in a particular row

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

Let us say we have the years 2000 to 2010 (columns A to K) in row 1 and underneath we have many rows that have entries for some of these years. For each of the rows with data, let us say column L has an arbitrary year in it (between 2000 and 2010). Is there a way of checking if there are any entries to the left of this arbitrary year in that row.

For example let's say row 5 has values for the years 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, and 2010. In column L, let us say the arbitrary year is 2007. The formula should check if row 5 has any values before 2007. Since it does have one (it has a value for 2006), it will return true. If the arbitrary year in row L was 2005, then it would have returned false (since there are only values from 2006 and onwards in that row).

I tried doing an Hlookup with an offset but it doesn't seem to work.

Any help would be great and if you need further clarification please let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this formula in M2 copied down

`=IF(COUNTA(A2:K2),INDEX(A$1:K$1,MATCH(1,INDEX((A2:K2<>"")+0,0),0))<L2)`

That should work in any version of Excel with any type of data, depending on specific data type in rows (text or numeric) or Excel version there may be shorter formulas available